# Artifact dependencies: good practice having jar files with domain events shared?

Tags: jar, dependencies, artifact

I have a couple of components (as jar files) that share another artifact (always jar) that contains only domain event classes (pojos) for an Akka project. Having this sort of artifact is it generally a good or bad practice?